# PowerPoint ThemeColorScheme derived colors/shades

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto

wrestling with the way VSTO/PowerPoint handles colors, I am looking for a way to get the colors derived from the color scheme (see image, interesting portion framed in red).

I tried `TintAndShade` and various other transformations in the RGB space, but I can't seem to reproduce what PowerPoint is doing to generate these colors. Has anyone succeeded in getting these colors (programmatically, and independent of the actual color scheme used, of course)?

[image: Colors I'm looking for in red]

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
eDude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this article](http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007.php).

In essence, the transformation is applied in the HSL space (Hue/Saturation/Lightness). The conversion from RGB to HSL is somewhat tedious to implement, but is a straightforward mathematical operation.

Once the principal `ThemeColorScheme` colors are converted from RGB to HSL, the following transformation will go from the main color to the different shades:

`L = L*Abs(fraction) + (fraction > 0 ? 1 : 0) * (1-fraction)`

Where `fraction` is the percent value given in the tool tip. Convert back from HSL to RGB and you have the colors from the picture.

From my experimenting, then fractions used to build the PowerPoint depend on the L value of the main color. My best guess for the limits are:

- For colors with L < 0.8, the fractions are 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, -0.75 and -0.5
- For colors with L >= 0.8, but not 1.0, the fractions are -0.9, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25 and -0.1
- For white, the fractions are -0.95, -0.85, -0.75, -0.65 and -0.5

With that, I could programmatically build the whole PowerPoint color palette.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint object model doesn't provide anything for that.

You may try to use the [OfficeTheme.ThemeColorScheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.officetheme.themecolorscheme?view=office-pia#Microsoft_Office_Core_OfficeTheme_ThemeColorScheme) property which gets a [ThemeColorScheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.themecolorscheme?view=office-pia) object that represents the color scheme of a Microsoft Office theme. The [ThemeColorScheme.Colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.themecolorscheme.colors?view=office-pia#Microsoft_Office_Core_ThemeColorScheme_Colors_Microsoft_Office_Core_MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex_) method allows getting a color in the color scheme of a Microsoft Office theme.

Comment: Those colors are created by a set of built-in algorithms in PowerPoint. They are not editable or configurable. As an alternative, you can create a set of Custom Colors, which will appear below the auto-generated palette: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/06/xml-hacking-custom-colors/